# Will it be appropriate to post usage samples for evaluation?

Tags: discussion

I am teaching English for kids as a hobby and I am constantly developing whole sentences to show word/prase/idiom usage. Then tasks are issued to translate those sentences from native language to English.

Will it be appropriate, if I post those sentences on ELL kindly asking to review them and give some comments on their correctness, both grammatically and stylistically?

Comment: I think this would be proofreading, which is off-topic for this site; if you provide an example I could tell you whether I feel that _that_ example is on-topic, but it mightn't necessarily apply to other questions that you might post. Proofreading questions are limited in their usefulness to future visitors, so I'd tentatively say, with next to no information, that the types of questions you're proposing wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: @jimsug http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35053/asking-for-text-review-tom-and-botswana-adventure